# When should a semicolon be used in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a beginner in Dart/Flutter and tried reading [this](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour) but I still couldn't understand when to use a semicolon. Why aren't we inserting a semicolon at the end of every bracket of a widget?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two kinds of statements in Dart: **simple statements** and **compound statements**.

### Put semicolons at the end of simple statements

Examples:

- `print('hello world');`
- `return myValue;`
- `var x = 4;`

### Don't put semicolons at the end of compound statements

Compound statements have code blocks whose scope is defined by curly braces `{ }`. You don't use semicolons after the closing curly brace.

**if-statement example:**

```
if (x > 2) {
  print(x);
}
```

Here `print(x)` is a simple statement so it needed a semicolon, but the if-statement closing brace didn't need one.

Other examples of compound statements include loops, switch statements, and function blocks.

### Don't put semicolons between the items of a list

In Dart, the items of a list are separated by commas, like so:

```dart
var myList = [1, 2, 3];
```

The semicolon goes after the list's closing square bracket to indicate that the statement is complete, but the list items themselves used commas.

You can also format lists vertically if you add a comma after the last item, like so:

```dart
var myList = [
  1, 
  2, 
  3,
];
```

In Flutter layouts you often have lists of widgets that follow this same pattern.

### Flutter example

Have a look at this example in Flutter:

```dart
class MyWidet extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        width: 300,
        color: Colors.blue,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child:
          Wrap(
            children: [
              MyWidget(),
              MyWidget(),
              MyWidget(),
              MyWidget(),
              MyWidget(),
            ],
        ),
      ),
    ); // end of the return statement
  }
}
```

Note the following things:

- Neither of the `}` closing braces (for the `MyWidet` class and `build` method) use semicolons.
- Parameter lists (dividing things like `width`, `color`, `child`, etc) are lists. They use commas.
- The children of Wrap are also in a list. They use commas.
- Although long and spread out, there is only one simple statement here, the `return` statement, so there is only one semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

Statements end with a semicolon (e.g. print, assignments, increments ...) 
Code blocks do not need semicolons (e.g. classes, functions, if blocks)

To answer your question, usually you'll pass in a widget into a parameter of a parent widget. In this case, you'll use commas, just like in any other class i.e. each widget is not a statement but rather a code block or more specifically, instance of a class

However, in the build function, you'll use semicolon since the widget is being returned (a statement).

For example,

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(...); // semicolon used to signify the end of a statement
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We use `;` because we terminate a statement in most languages same in dart/flutter .
Specifically for dart/flutter widgets are 
Tree structrue(parent and child widgets) according to your implementation if you are using inner widget wrapped with outer widget then you must use `;` after **End of outer widget** or if you are returning a widget then after widget completion. 
For example. See [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab)