# Why don't use semicolon at end of class in dart language?

Tags: android, dart, language-design

Dart programming language.
My question is
**Why don't use semicolons at end of class in dart language?**
I tried to find the answer to this question but the answer I have gained is that the answer does not have a proper meaning of my question.
**The answer is**

"Don't put semicolons at the end of compound statements Compound statements have code blocks whose scope is defined by curly braces. You don't use semicolons after the closing curly brace"

Comment: you can see python and kotlin . they dont using semicolon like in c.Compiler desiners decide it

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62369028/when-should-a-semicolon-be-used-in-dart-flutter#:~:text=Don't%20put%20semicolons%20at,after%20the%20closing%20curly%20brace.

Comment: Class declarations are not compound statements, but the real question is why did you expect otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is: the language designers chose this to be the case. And this is not just the case for Dart. Swift, Rust, Python and many other languages do not accept a semicolon to end a class definition.

You can read the official Dart language specifications here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.10.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is: because that is the definition. It's man made. It was a decision by the language creators. There is no other external reason to be found.

Why they made that decision is probably not extensively documented. It wasn't needed. There is no need for a semicolon, so none was used.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need semicolons after curly braces that enclose other statements or declarations.  The closing brace itself already acts as a statement terminator.  Requiring a semicolon would be redundant.

Some languages (notably C and C++) require semicolons after class (`struct` in C) declarations because their syntax allows putting an identifier between the closing brace and the semicolon as a mechanism to declare a variable with that type:

```cpp
class CPlusPlusClass {
  int member = 0;
} instanceOfCPlusPlusClass;

// An anonymous class type.
class { 
  int member = 0;
} instanceOfAnonymousClass;
```

whereas in Dart you'd need two separate declarations:

```dart
class DartClass {
  int member = 0;
}

DartClass instanceOfDartClass = DartClass();
```

and Dart does not allow anonymous classes.